# URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have this error when I try test connection with facebook in symfony ..

[image]

code symfony:

```
      /**
       * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
       * @Rest\Post("/accounts/facebook/login/callback/")
       */
      public function FbAction(Request $request) 
      {
          $fb = new Facebook([
            'app_id' => 'id app', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
            'app_secret' => 'secret app',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11'
          ]);

      if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
          $token = $request->request->get('token');
          .
          .
          .
          .

          return new JsonResponse(array('token' => $jwt));

      }
  }
```

in application facebook I add this url in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs
:

> http://127.0.0.1/myproject/web/app_dev.php/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

and I check if this url is valid or not in Redirect URI Validator

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your URL is valid? 
I think your URL's look like this within the whitelisted list in facebook OAuth settings
`http://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php/accounts/facebook/login/callback/`

Comment: yes I add this url in whitelisted list in facebook OAuth settings and this valid url but when I try connected in redirect uri I found domain application oauth and not this url